# For which values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is the matrix $A$ strictly diagonally dominant?

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, spectral-radius

Let we have the following matrix:

$$ \begin{matrix}
    1 & \alpha & 0 \\
    \beta & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

Is the matrix $A$ strictly diagonally dominant? Or better said, for which values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is the matrix $A$ strictly diagonally dominant?

---

I know that a matrix is strictly dominant if $|a_{ii}|>\sum_{j=1,j\neq{i}}^n |a_{ij}|$

So we've got the following:

$|a_{11}|=1>\alpha + 0=\alpha$ ; So the first condition is that $\alpha>1$

$|a_{22}|=1>|\beta| + 1$ ; **But it is impossible to be $|\beta|<0$**

$|a_{33}|=1>0 + 1=1$ ; **And also, $1$ is not bigger than $1$...**

So isn't it possible for A to be strictly diagonally dominant?

Comment: The problem appears already with the second row (you  forgot absalute value of beta).

Comment: Oh that's true! So is it impossible for A to be strictly diagonally dominant? Or I can't do it like this?

Comment: Such matrix cannot be strictly diagonally dominant.

Comment: ok, thanks! But I've got a question; my real problem was that I had to find the values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ so that the conditions to be convergent the Jacobi method are fulfilled. What I wanted to do was to see that the matrix $A$ was strictly diagonally dominant (of course, now I know that it is not) and say which are the values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Is there any other way to know for which values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is Jacobi's method convergent?

Comment: Oh sorry, I've found this: A sufficient (but not necessary) condition for the method to converge is that the matrix A is strictly or irreducibly diagonally dominant.

Comment: Let's suppose that $A$ is the Jacobi Matrix of your problem, then if $\|A\|_\infty<1$ you have convergence. However, you can't use that here. You may want to check the eigenvalue and if their are all, in module, less than 1 you have convergence.

Comment: Compute the spectral radius of $D^{-1}(L+U)$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_method), you'll obtain $\rho=\sqrt{1+\alpha \beta},$ which has to be smaller than $1.$ And you're done... one is positive, the other negative, and their product not smaller than $-1.$

Comment: @user376343 so it would converge if $\alpha <0$ or $\beta <0$; am I right?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, then it is if $-1<\alpha \beta <0.$

Comment: Why @user376343? I've done like this: $\sqrt{1+\alpha \beta} <1; 1+\alpha \beta<1; \alpha \beta <0$ So $\alpha$ or $\beta$ has to be negative

Comment: But the value under square root needs to be non-negative.